# Tool to parse text for possible Wikipedia links

Tags: parsing, hyperlink, wikipedia

Does a tool exist that can parse text and output that text, hyper-linked to Wikipedia entries for words of interest?

For example, I'd like a tool that could turn something like:

> The most popular search algorithm on a
>   sorted list is the binary search.

Into:

> The most popular [search algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_algorithm) on a
>   [sorted list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorted_list) is the [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search).

It would be wonderful if Wikipedia had an API which would do this since they would be best equipped to determine what "words of interests" are.

In my example I simply linked all combinations which linked directly to an entry except for The and most.

Comment: Seems like the first step would be to get access to a complete list of Wikipedia entries...

Comment: Or query against Wikipedia a whole bunch of times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a tool that does exactly what you're asking for.
http: //wikify.appointment.at/
It's not perfect, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

You have two separate problems to solve here:

1. Deciding which words should be linked
2. Determining if there's a suitable entry to link these words to

Now, (2) is simpler, though it's also somewhat problematic. Wikipedia seems to have [an API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot#APIs_for_bots) that allows you to gather data efficiently, and they also allow "screen scraping". But there's a problem with disambiguation - sometimes you might hit not the entry you wanted. For example, [python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python) links to a disambiguation page, as it can be a programming language, a snake and a couple of other things.

(1) Is much harder, though. You can take the "simple approach" and attempt to find links for all non-trivial nouns (or even noun/adjective pairs). Non-trivial here means omitting words like "fiend, word, computer" etc. 
But This would result in a plethora of links, which isn't convenient to read. It's really up to you to decide what's interesting in the text, and this depends a lot on the text itself. In an article for professional programmers, do you really want to link to "search algorithm" every time? But for beginners, perhaps you do.

To conclude, I strongly doubt there's a single general-purpose tool that will do the trick for you. But you surely have all the options at your hand, and something need-specific can be coded without too much effort.

Answer (score 1):

Silviu Cucerzan of Microsoft Research tackled this problem.  Well, not the problem of inserting the links, but the general issue of determining what entities are being mentioned in a some piece of text.  Fortunately for you, he used Wikipedia articles as his set of entities.  His paper, "Large-Scale Named Entity Disambiguation Based on Wikipedia Data", is available on his [website](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/silviu/default.aspx).  Direct link: [pdf](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/silviu/emnlp07.pdf).